# Should I simplify question if it drastically changes the question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923217/css-only-no-transition-on-load/39926304?noredirect=1#comment67222803_39926304), that asks about a problem I'm having getting a specific piece of code to work. After toying with it more for days after asking the question I believe I could simplify the code/question to show the exact difference that is causing it to "break", and thus hopefully making it easier to find the answer. Essentially I'd be making it more concise and general (and better in my opinion) than a question specifically including all the variants in my long somewhat complex code. Any answer that would solve the concise problem would certainly work for my code as well the extra code is just clutter masking the issue.

However, as you imagine this would drastically change the question (only the format/content, it'd be asking the exact same underlying question) and possibly make existing answer look irrelevant or wrong just for including the original questions code. I could ask the more concise simple question as another question but it might be considered a duplicate because, again, the underlying question is the same.

Comment: you should simplify it as long as it makes sense with mandatory information to solve the issue, rest simpling it won't be considered as duplicate if it's not , many smart guys are here too

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's appropriate to remove information (whether that's code or a part of the question text) that is not actually relevant to the question being asked.  Removing noise from a question without actually changing what the question is asking is one of the primary use cases for editing.